# Psychology behind repeated viewing of certain pictures and songs

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, music, aesthetics

Often it happens that we like to frequently listen to a particular tune or song or view some pictures or images repeatedly time after time. What are the reasons and psychology behind this?

Comment: Related (newer, but duplicate?): [Why do we come to like some songs after re-listening to them a few times?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/17967/21) Has a better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a difficult to say I assume many kind of past memories* linked with emotions subconsciously play certainly a critical role nevertheless I found an interesting link (http://www.gizmag.com/predicting-hit-songs/20939/) which is about a formula on how to find out the next hit song.

---

*by memories I mean more kind of episodic memories rather than semantic although it could be semantic if someone would be expressed of a song by its lyrics.