# Why do we come to like some songs after re-listening to them a few times?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, music

It happens in the case of some songs that they don't strike as extremely good the first time one listens to them but after listening to them a few more times, one suddenly starts loving them. What difference does the re-listening do?

Comment: [Relevant paper](http://bora.uib.no/bitstream/handle/1956/594/BORA_PSPR04.pdf;jsessionid=A4A34885BE4723CE42825B3C240B4535.bora-uib_worker?sequence%253D1)

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Psychology behind repeated viewing of certain pictures and songs](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5068/21) (Although not a particularly good question, nor answer.)

Answer (score 5):

The phenomenom you describe is called [Mere-exposure effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere-exposure_effect) :

> The mere-exposure effect is a psychological phenomenon by which people
> tend to develop a preference for things merely because they are
> familiar with them. In social psychology, this effect is sometimes
> called the familiarity principle. The effect has been demonstrated
> with many kinds of things, including words, Chinese characters,
> paintings, pictures of faces, geometric figures, and **sounds**.
>
> The mere-exposure effect has been explained by a two-factor theory
> that posits that **repeated exposure** of a stimulus **increases perceptual
> fluency** which is the ease with which a stimulus can be processed.
> Perceptual fluency, in turn, **increases positive affect**.

The perceptual fluency is explained in detail by the [article](http://bora.uib.no/bitstream/handle/1956/594/BORA_PSPR04.pdf;jsessionid=A4A34885BE4723CE42825B3C240B4535.bora-uib_worker?sequence%253D1) in @mrt comment.